# Android Snake Example. Is onDraw executed on Handlers thread or on the UI thread?

Tags: android, handler

I'm taking code directly from Snake Example:

C:\Users\MyUser\android-eclipse\sdk\samples\android-19\legacy\Snake

```
        public class SnakeView extends TileView {

            private RefreshHandler mRedrawHandler = new RefreshHandler();

            class RefreshHandler extends Handler {

                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    SnakeView.this.update();
                    SnakeView.this.invalidate();
                }

                public void sleep(long delayMillis) {
                    this.removeMessages(0);
                    sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
                }
            };

            public void update() {
                if (mMode == RUNNING) {
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    if (now - mLastMove > mMoveDelay) {
                        clearTiles();
                        updateSnake();
                        mLastMove = now;
                    }
                    mRedrawHandler.sleep(mMoveDelay);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                //Draw stuff in here
            }   
        }
```

Yes I understand that invalidate which is called in handleMessage will force an onDraw to be called. Is the onDraw executed on the handlers thread or is it still executed on the UI thread. I like this example but I would like to move onDraws work off of the UI thread.

P.S. By the way I think the way is to pass the canvas to a new method that exists on the thread and then use the canvas to draw with. Is that how that would be done? Also currently I'm under the impression that onDraw runs on the UI thread is Snake example.

I have been curious always as well how I can pass canvas around so many times in different method and it still retains its draws is something I don't fully understand yet.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `OnDraw()` function is running on UI thread. Most of `onDraw()` function of View and its descendants are running in UI-thread.
In the fact, the Handler is a helper class to pass Message from non UI-Thread to UI-Thread. When you call function of handler, this function will run on the thread who calls it.

**EDIT**

The parameter in `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` is passed by some when rendering. It is gotten by somefunction (e.g. `SurfaceHolder.lock()`) in rendering cycle, and will be post (`Canvas.unlockAndPost`) after `onDraw()`. You can pass it as parameter in `onDraw()` because it has not been post.

Comment: This is the answer then. Perhaps I could get some more info about canvas being a parameter?

Comment: You can directly pass the canvas as parameter when you call the function.